# MariaDB select from inner joined query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery, inner-join

I am not able to further select from a joined subquery.

I have data in three tables: "events", "records" and "work_list". Each table has one piece of the puzzle where work_list is the shortest and contains top-level data, and the events table tracks many tiny frequent events.

I need to calculate many statistical variables from the events based on some key variables defined in work_list like weighted moving average etc. I have those metrics ready and working, but I have problems filtering the data in events based on selected parameters stored in work_list.

Here is code that does not work. The SELECT * is not important, I will change it to be more meaningful later, it is for clarity. However, I have tried many selections in place of the * without success.

What is wrong with this query from subquery?

Query example 1:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT events.id, events.type,events.timestamp, work_list.task
    FROM 
        ( events
            INNER JOIN records ON events.record_id = records.id
            INNER JOIN work_list ON records.work_list_id = work_list.id
        )
    WHERE work_list.customer_number = '1234' AS subquery
);
```

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as subquery ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 8`

The inner joined subquery works and it returns a normal table.

Query example 2:

```
SELECT events.id, events.type,events.timestamp, work_list.task
FROM (
        events
    INNER JOIN records ON events.record_id = records.id
    INNER JOIN work_list ON records.work_list_id = work_list.id
    )
WHERE work_list.customer_number = '1234';
```

I tried using parenthesis in different orders, and I changed selected variables in `SELECT events.id, events.type,events.timestamp, work_list.task`. I wonder if this is a poor way of doing this. I have the calculation part. So even if there might be better structures for this, I am interested in solutions that maintain this structure.

The goal of this phase is to filter the events table for further queries that are coded on top of it replacing the `SELECT *`.

These are the final calculations made earlier which I plan to use when I figure out the problem with Query example 1.

Query example 3:

```
SELECT *, ((SUM(rate * diff) OVER (ORDER BY startTime
     ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) /
     (SUM(diff) OVER(ORDER BY startTime
     ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))) as rate_WMA
FROM (
    SELECT id, startTime, counts, diff, (counts / diff)*3600 as rate
    FROM (
        SELECT id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp))AS diff, SUM(change) as counts, MIN(timestamp) as startTime
        FROM `the filered subquery here`
        GROUP BY id 
    ) AS subquery
    WHERE diff > 0 
) AS totaltotal;
```

Comment: Beware of unnecessary randomly added brackets

Comment: There does not seem any point in a subquery here

Comment: Thats a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT QUERY !!!!!!

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: I dont, I could probably work it out if I had a bit of database to play with (dbfiddle would work for that). I am certainly not going to spend my time setting up a database and data,  hence my last suggestion. I know those youtube vids, they completely miss the fact people dump a poorly asked question and then sit back expecting the world, then get upset when someone suggests they make a bit more effort asking the quesiton and providing a testbed

Comment: Not to mention the addition of a much more complex query AFTER the initial question

Comment: Please remember, we are not your paid staff, in most cases we are someone elses paid staff just here to help out in a few quiet moments

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra parenthesis (no need for those) and the alias for the subquery should be placed after the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT events.id, events.type,events.timestamp, work_list.task
  FROM events
    INNER JOIN records ON events.record_id = records.id
    INNER JOIN work_list ON records.work_list_id = work_list.id
  WHERE work_list.customer_number = '1234'
) AS subquery;
```